# Change button's content font when it contains font-awesome icon

Tags: css, kendo-ui, font-awesome

I have a *Kendo* grid with action buttons inside which contains *font-awesome* icons inside them. What I want to do is to change the font of the button's text. But when you change the font, it overrides the *font-awesome* and the icons are not displayed (only empty squares are shown instead, which is the expected behavior).

The generated html is:

```
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext action-btn fa fa-pencil-square-o k-grid-Edit" href="#" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">
    <span class=" "></span>Edit
</a>
```

I am gonna share an image of how it looks inside chrome tools:
[image]
My question is how to I override only the button's content font, not the `::before` which is the actual *font-awesome* element.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g32g1Lzg/) to try it.

Comment: Have you tried using the :not() css command. [have a look at this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: You welcome. However I would still suggest the other solution, as it is the solution most accepted as per Font-awesome specs. You also wouldn't need to add CSS for each button. One fix for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that this html element was generated by Kendo UI I am using, not by me. So I had to override the css rules, instead of changing the DOM structure.

I resolved the problem easily using these css rules:

```
.k-button.fa::before{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.k-button{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add the font awesome icons as per the [websites example](http://fontawesome.io/examples/). In an `<i>` tag within the `<a>` tag. That way the font-family of the `<a>` tag is not affected.

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g32g1Lzg/1/)

Comment: I get your idea, but I am not able to change the DOM since it is generated by the Kendo UI